# MessageBox properties?

Tags: sapui5

I was using the `sap.ca.ui.message.message`namespace to create an error popup. I noticed this was deprecated and now I am using the correct `sap.m.Messagebox.error` namespace. However I am confused on the properties I can use for this dialog box.The deprecated namespace has properties that the correct one does not, such as "Details". I did see however that `MessageBox.show` can use the Details property. Can I still define these properties? Where is a list of the properties? Neither of the links below answer my question and the Explored link only shows a few simple examples.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.MessageBox%20/samples
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sap.m.MessageBox.[error](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.html#.error) is not parameter "Details". Please, what exactly do you want to display in the details?

EDITED 17:25 010217:

You can still use sap.m.MessageBox.[show](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.html#.show) and its property details, just set error icon:

```
icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
```

Here is working jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/cukahazise/1/edit?html,js,output).

EDITED 19:38 010217:

The parameter "Details" also works for sap.m.MessageBox.error, here is jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/diferuguhu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: A longer text that a user can choose to see or not, same as sap.m.MessageBox.show can do in it's mOptions.show

Comment: Ah okay, so why would I ever want to use sap.m.MessageBox.error if I can use sap.m.MessageBox.show?

Comment: You can also use sap.m.MessageBox.error if you want http://jsbin.com/diferuguhu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That was the essence of my question. How come the details attribute isn't listed in the `sap.m.MessageBox.error`? Is the documentation not completely accurate yet?

Comment: 'Tis a pity, I keep noticing this reoccurring theme